# Make altair scatterplot assign different colours instead of shades of the same colour

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, altair

I want to replicate this image from altair generated with this code from the examples:

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
x='Vth',
y='mob',
color='Thickness',
tooltip=['Temperature', 'Thickness']
).interactive()e
source = Table_3
```

[Altair example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gJdy.png)

However my dataset choice for colour is numerical: 
[Table_3.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUafi.png)

this is the code i Have:

```
source = Table_3

alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Vth',
    y='mob',
    color='Thickness',
    tooltip=['Temperature', 'Thickness']
).interactive()
```

This causes altair to give me shades of the same colour. i want it to divide it like in the example:

[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ZiF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Altair that the number is in fact nominal, not quantitative by adding `:N` to your "Thickness" field.

```
alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Vth',
    y='mob',
    color='Thickness:N',
    tooltip=['Temperature', 'Thickness']
).interactive()
```